# Нужна ли запятая после "выступающие из полумрака"?

Tags: запятые, однородные-члены

*Все трое зачарованно разглядывали выступающие из полумрака, ни разу не повторяющиеся узоры и так поднялись по ней, переходя от цветка к цветку и от яблока к яблоку.*

Answer (score 1):

Да, так как в данном случае это однородные определения, которые выражены причастным оборотом с зависимым словом (*из полумрака* и *ни разу*), к тому же с запятой текст гораздо более понятен. Вот здесь есть пример употребления подобной конструкции (*Черные, гладко причесанные волосы*): https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/713-232_odnorodnye_i_neodnorodnye_opredeleniya.html

Comment: В чём однородность?

Comment: В синтаксисе в основном, думаю: оба определения это причастные обороты с зависимыми словами и описывают существительное как качественные прилагательные (какие узоры?). Если вы хотите описать именно "ни разу не повторяющиеся узоры" (то есть слово "узоры" в таком случае не имеет своей семантики достаточной для понятия предложения), то можно не ставить запятой. Но я бы ставила: и "узоры" мне кажутся вполне самодостаточным словом, и с запятыми предложение лучше читается.

Comment: Ну так в плане синтаксиса любые прилагательные однородные. Так что синтаксическая однородность не рассматривается, рассматривается смысловая. Всё-таки они неоднородные (освещение и повторяемость). *и с запятыми предложение лучше читается* — вот это и есть причина. А почему лучше читается? Потому что обороты длинные для одной безостановочной фразы. Но без запятой тоже допустимо. На этом сайте очень важно объяснение ответа, чтобы оно было правильным, часто правильным является только само решение.

Comment: Не соглашусь: однородность - это прежде всего категория синтаксическая, и многие словари подчеркивают, что на однородность указывает и тот факт, что конструкции выражены одинаковыми членами предложениями. По-моему, гораздо более весомым аргументом является наличие зависимых слов (то есть схожие конструкции причастных оборотов), чем просто "лучше читается". Цель сайта благородная, но, простите, мне кажется, что в языке редко бывают однозначные ответы, скорее более и менее вероятные - делюсь своим обоснованным мнением. Однако, вы точно правы с уточнением: однородность - понятие неоднородное:)

Comment: Мы говорим не за однородность в общем, а за ту, что используется в данной теме, а там смысловая, только она рассматривается в правилах. Там даже речь не об однородности непосредственно, а об "однородных определениях" и "неоднородных определениях". Длина фразы играет большую роль, часто обособление делается чисто из-за этого. *мне кажется, что в языке редко бывают однозначные ответы, скорее более и менее вероятные* — ну да, тогда правильное решение — это более вероятное, а если есть варианты, надо всех их указать, чтоб спрашивающий не исключил менее вероятное. Тогда это полный ответ.

Comment: Да, мой ответ мог бы быть более развернутым - так что спасибо за уточняющий вопрос. Но главное, по-моему, это однородность конструкций в данном случае (не семантическая однородность отдельных слов и не сама по себе длина, так как вполне могло бы существовать подобное предложение без запятых, если бы они не были однородными, например: "выступающие из полумрака восхитительные до чертиков узоры" - а именно соединение схожих конструкций и отдаленно схожего описательного смысла).

Comment: Такая же ситуация. И даже более: из-за меньшей структурной однородности ещё хуже звучит в одну неделимую фразу. Где такое в правилах? Распространённые обороты обычно с запятой.

Comment: У Розенталя есть вот что: Несогласованные определения, как правило, однородны: Вошёл молодой человек лет двадцати пяти, блещущий здоровьем, со смеющимися щеками, губами и глазами (Гонч.). То есть наоборот, вопреки структурной неоднородности.

Comment: Это согласованные определения: причастия совпадают в роде, числе и падеже с определяемым словом. В вашем примере определения как раз-таки однородны из-за структуры (синтаксиса): практически все являются несогласованными определениями и находятся в одинаковых/похожих отношениях с зависимым словом.

Comment: Вы говорите, что определения однородны, когда конструкции однородны (согласованность и схожесть). А Розенталь вам говорит, что нет. То есть однородностью конструкций не ограничивается.

Answer (score 1):

**В качестве вступления** приведу два замечания.

1. Необходимость постановки запятой в приведенном предложении кажется очевидной, но объяснение причины вызывает трудности. Почему? А это задача **не решена у Розенталя** (там нет похожих примеров), и надо ее решать самим по аналогии с теми правилами, которые приводятся в данной теме.
2. **Комментарии** также меня заинтересовали. Собеседники не могут понять друг друга, как будто вовсе не слышат или не слушают. Почему? Ведь эта тема для нас хорошо знакомая, она изучается одной из первой в средней школе. А дело в том, что никто не приводит **четких определений однородности**, с которыми были бы согласны оба. А если этого нет, то понимания не будет, сколько ни продолжай беседу.

**Ответ**

1. Однородность бывает ГРАММАТИЧЕСКАЯ И СЕМАНТИЧЕСКАЯ. Грамматически однородные члены относятся к одному слову и отвечают на один и тот же вопрос, но при этом ПО СМЫСЛУ они могут быть однородными или неоднородными, а также уточнять, пояснять или обобщать друг друга.

К однородным относят такие члены предложения, которые **однородны как грамматически, так и по смыслу.** Это  члены с определенной семантикой, независимые между собой, но при этом раскрывающие одну и ту же тему (в частном случае это синонимы).  Однородные определения относятся непосредственно к существительному и могут образовать с ним отдельное сочетание, например:  дождливая, грязная, темная (= неприятная) осень – дождливая осень, грязная осень, темная осень.

2. Однородность бывает  **СБЛИЖЕННАЯ (контекстуальная)** – например, при наличии причинно-следственной связи между определениями: *темная, безлунная ночь.* Иногда сближение делается по ФОРМАЛЬНЫМ признакам, в частности это касается ВЗАИМНОГО РАСПОЛОЖЕНИЯ одиночного определения и определительного оборота.
3. Например: *Они вошли в маленькую, СКРЫТУЮ ЗА ШПАЛЕРАМИ комнату*. Одиночное определение, стоящее **перед определительным оборотом** считается однородным, хотя признаки разные. Дело в том, что в этом случае сложно определить границу между ними. (Этот вариант рассмотрен в правилах Розенталя.) Аналогичная ситуация будет, если рядом расположить два оборота.
4. **Поэтому ответ будет такой**. Определения  в приведенном предложении можно назвать условно однородными (семантически они скорее разные) **по формальному признаку,** так как определительные обороты расположены последовательно, один за другим. Запятая определяет **границу** между двумя оборотами, обозначая их состав. Некоторое сближение можно усмотреть по общему восприятию или впечатлению. Интонация перечислительная.